# Returning a collection via a repository using Moq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit, moq

I'm relatively new to unit testing and ASP.NET MVC as a whole and I'm trying to write my first unit test against a simple controller action and a repository (as seen below) using `Moq`.

**ISubmissionRepository.cs**

```
public interface ISubmissionRepository
{
    IList<Submission> GetRecent(int limit = 10);
}
```

**HomeController.cs:**

```
/* Injected using Unit DIC */
public HomeController(ISubmissionRepository submissionRepository)
{
    _submissionRepo = submissionRepository;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{

    var latestList = _submissionRepo.GetRecent();
    var viewModel = new IndexViewModel {
        NumberOfSubmissions = latestList.Count(),
        LatestSubmissions = latestList
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Below is the unit test I'm writing, however my mocked repository call doesn't appear to be returning anything and I've no idea why. Am I mocking my repository call correctly?

**HomeControllerTest.cs**

```
[Test]
public void Index()
{
    IList<Submission> submissions = new List<Submission>
    {
        new Submission {Credit = "John Doe", Description = "Hello world", ID = 1, Title = "Example Post"},
        new Submission {Credit = "John Doe", Description = "Hello world", ID = 2, Title = "Example Post"}
    };

    Mock<ISubmissionRepository> mockRepo = new Mock<ISubmissionRepository>();
    mockRepo.Setup(x => x.GetRecent(2)).Returns(submissions);

    /* 
    * This appears to return null when a breakpoint is set
    var obj = mockRepo.Object;
    IList<Submission> temp = obj.GetRecent(2);
    */

    controller = new HomeController(mockRepo.Object);
    ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

    Assert.NotNull(result);
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<IndexViewModel>(result);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your controller you're calling:

```
var latestList = _submissionRepo.GetRecent();
```

Your mock is setup for `GetRecent(2)`.

Modify your mock setup to:

```
mockRepo.Setup(x => x.GetRecent()).Returns(submissions);
```

***EDIT***

Also your assert should be:

```
Assert.IsInstanceOf<IndexViewModel>(result.Model);
```

Comment: `result.Model` seemed to do the job perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
 mockRepo.Setup(x => x.GetRecent(2)).Returns(submissions);
```

Tells moq to return the collection when it is called with param 2.  your controller calls it as

```
var latestList = _submissionRepo.GetRecent();
```

These are seperate setups up in Moq, so your result isn't returned.  you can remove the 2 in the test or make your controller call it with 2 to get the return.

EDIT - update answer

try setting your mock up as:

```
mockRepo.Setup(x => x.GetRecent(It.Is<int>(i => i == 2))).Returns(submissions);
```

That tells it only to return when it see's 2 in the argument list.  You controller will also need to call it with 2 for the return to work.

Otherwise, set it up as this to be agnostic of the parameter

```
mockRepo.Setup(x => x.GetRecent(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(submissions);
```

Comment: I've tried to remove any reference to 2 from arguments and the call still appears to be returning null instead of the collection?

Comment: You may have done this already but try using It.IsAny<int>() as the match condition to see if GetRecent() is being called at all. If it is being called then it probably matches GetRecent(10) - the default argument.

Comment: @AlanT Yeah, I have tried this but to no avail. This issue really has me stumped.

Comment: Thanks for your help Slickism. This seemed to help fix the problem along with Dimitar's solution above.